# SQL Server Merge Statement After Update of a Column in Source Table

Tags: sql-server, merge

I am attempting to use a merge statement on two tables. `Course` and `EmployeeCourseStatus`. When the Column `Course.Rev` is updated, I want a new row inserted into `EmployeeCourseStatus` table with the new Revision.

`EmployeeCourseStatus` is the table used to track Employees Progress on different courses. It is set up with a Composite key with columns `EmployeeID` and `CourseID`.

`Course` contains all the information about the Course such as `CourseName`,`ValidFor`,and `Rev`.

I want to add a new row everytime a course is updated so I can keep the course history for all employees and not have to reassign employees to each course when a course is updated to a new revision

So I have tried using a Merge Statement but I having trouble with the composite key. I then plan to use an update trigger on the `Course` table

```
MERGE [dbo].[EmployeeCourseStatus] as ECS
USING [dbo].[Course]  AS C
ON ECS.[CourseID] = C.[CourseID] AND
ECS.Rev = C.Rev
WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN
   INSERT([EmployeeID],[CourseID],[Status],[CompletionDate],[ValidFor],[Rev]) 
   VALUES(
   (SELECT EmployeeID FROM [dbo].[EmployeeCourseStatus] ),
   [CourseID],
   null,
   null,
   [ValidFor],
   [Rev]);
```

I would like the result of this merge statement to insert new rows into `EmployeeCourseStatus` when `Course` is updated with `Course.Rev`.

Comment: You should consider using an After Update Trigger on Course table.

Comment: @ShikharArora That's the plan but I need to figure out the Merge statement first

Comment: Your merge is not inserting dbo.EmployeeCourseStatus.Rev - at what point is that meant to happen?

Comment: @AlwaysLearning oh yeah, you're right! I'll add it now to the question